# Find out if sample data models a linear, polynomial, exponential or logarithmic growth with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, pattern-recognition

is there a library for ruby out there, which support me in finding out whether a sample of values x model linear, polynomial, exponential or logarithmic growth?

like:

```
[1,2,3,4].linear? => true
[1,2,4,8].exponential? => true
```

it should support a kind of fuzziness, that is, if the sample contains [1,2,2.8,4], the linear relationship should however be recognized.

thank you very much.

Comment: You could try softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: As if [1,2,2,8,4] were linear. If your 'fuzziness' is that broad, then it could just about anything.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is one but it's simple enough to write:

```
class Array
  def linear?
    array = self.sort
    fuzzy_factor = 0.1 * array[0] # just threw this in as an example fuzzy factor, take your pick.
    difference = array[1]-array[0]
    !array.each_with_index.reject {|x,i|
      i == 0 ||
      x < array[i-1] + difference + fuzzy_factor &&
      x > array[i-1] + difference - fuzzy_factor }.any?
  end

  def exponential?
    array = self.sort
    fuzzy_factor = 0.1 * array[0]
    factor = array[1]/array[0]
    !array.each_with_index.reject { |x,i| i==0 ||
      x <array[i-1]*(factor+fuzzy_factor) &&
      x>array[i-1]*(factor-fuzzy_factor)}.any?
  end
end

[1,2,3,4].linear?
# true
[1,2,3,5].linear?
#false
[2,4,8,16].exponential?
#true
[2,4,8,16,3].exponential?
#false
```

EDIT: adding in fuzzy factor. I just put a random one in, change due to requirements.